# Java share parent class var with sub class

Tags: java, android, class, subclass, parent

This is an example of what I try to do in my android project:

I have a class Animals who is an abstract class as parents and class Dog and Cat as subclasses.
All animals have their own position.
I create a new Animals like this:

```
Animals oDog = new Dog(new Vector3(x,y,z));
```

I want to create a method in Animals class like:

```
public Vector3 getPosition(){
    return mPosition;
}
```

who's returning animals position and I don't have to rewrite the same method in all Animals subclasses.
I don't know how to do this properly and even if it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried doing that? Defining a method once in a parent so sublcasses inherit it is exactly why you can have subclasses.

Comment: In fact what i want to know is if i create an instance of Animals like i said with new Dog, every futur Dog i ll create will have his own position even if Animals is abstract?

Comment: Abstract classes can have normal fully implemented methods as well as abstract ones that don't define an implementation. `getPosition` would make sense to put in there in full. Every object that you create must be fully implemented. You can't have objects that don't have implementations for some methods. As such, regarless of how `Animal` defines `getPosition`, a `Dog` must have that method. If not, you would have to make `Dog` abstract again but you couldn't create `Dog` objects anymore because now, you need a subclass of dog that implements the remaining abstract methods.

Comment: @zapl If `getPosition` is not an abstract method (i.e. fully defined in `Animal`) then none of subclasses are obliged to re-define it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an abstract class without making any abstract method.

As long as you don't make your method abstract, it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Animal{

    private Vector3 position;

    public Animal(Vector3 pos){
        position = pos;
    }

    public Vector3 getPosition(){
        return mPosition;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{

    public Dog(Vector3 pos){
        super(pos);
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal{

    public Cat(Vector3 pos){
        super(pos);
    }
}
```

And you can then call `getPosition` on any concrete subclass of Animal

Comment: Question is over a year old :)

Comment: True, but it showed up for some reason in the first 50 questions displayed :))

Comment: Because it was modified for grammar mistakes. Anyways, good luck being accepted :)